# System.InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_Reservaion' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 App i'm trying to use an Ajax form to implement a search to my 'Reservation' repository.

My View: (Views/Reservation/Index):

```
@model IEnumerable<RentalsForceProject.Models.Reservation>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reservations Center";
    ViewBag.current = "Reservation";
}

@section featured { 
    @Html.Partial("_Navigator")
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "get",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "ReservaionList"
    }))
{
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" name="Search By Contact" />
}

<p>
    <input type="button" value="Create New" class="greenButton" style="margin-top:20px;" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Reservation")'"/>
</p>

@Html.Partial("_Reservation", Model)
```

My Partial view (Views/Reservation/_Reservation):

```
@model IEnumerable<RentalsForceProject.Models.Reservation>


<div id="ReservaionList" class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-ordered">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Reservation
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Dates
            </th>
            <th>
                # Nights
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>


        @foreach (var res in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @res.ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (res.Contact != null) {
                        @Html.ActionLink(res.Contact.FirstName + " " + res.Contact.LastName, "Details", "Contact", new { id=res.Contact.ID }, null)
                        //@res.Contact.LastName @:&nbsp; @res.Contact.LastName 
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (res.Request != null) {
                        @res.Request.StartDate @:- @res.Request.EndDate
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @res.calculteNights()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (res.Status != null) {
                        @res.Status
                    }
                </td>
                <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Reservation", new { id = res.ID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" }) | @Ajax.ActionLink("View", "Details", new { id = res.ID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" }) | @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = res.ID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" })</td>
            </tr>
        }  

    </table>
</div>
```

My Index ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null)
{
    if (unitOfWork.currentClient == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.currentClient = unitOfWork.currentClient;

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() && searchTerm != null)
            return PartialView("_Reservaion", unitOfWork.currentClient.getAllReservationsBySearchTerm(searchTerm));

         return View(unitOfWork.currentClient.getAllReservations());
    }  
}
```

When i lunch the 'search' button i can see it creates to nesessary model to the partial view, but nothing happens in the view.
I tried to use Chrome developers tools -> F12 - Network tab, and found out this exception:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_Reservaion' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Reservation/_Reservaion.aspx
~/Views/Reservation/_Reservaion.ascx
~/Views/Shared/_Reservaion.aspx
~/Views/Shared/_Reservaion.ascx
~/Views/Reservation/_Reservaion.cshtml
~/Views/Reservation/_Reservaion.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/_Reservaion.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/_Reservaion.vbhtml
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: 'Reservaion' vs 'Reservation'.